# Javasctipt class pattern with repeating class name

Tags: javascript

I want to emulate classes in javascript, and have come up with this scheme...

```
var Random = function(a){ // class name used here
    var Random = function(a){ // and used again here
        this.valueOf = function(){
            return Math.random()
        }
        this.under = function(limit){
            return this*limit
        }
        this.floor = function(limit){
            return Math.floor(this*limit)
        }
    }
    return new Random(a)
}

var rnd = Random()

console.log(rnd*20<<0)
```

The naming seems quite conventional to me, with class names in TitelCase and instances in camelCase. I wrap the class twice, so that I can return an instance, as I don't like using `new Thing` in my main code.

The thing that strikes me as most unusual is using the same class name for both wrappers. Is there any technical problem with this pattern?

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: There are lots of JS class libraries out there -- some of which support class derivation and base class access.  All the good polymorphism stuff.  Don't reinvent the wheel here.  Just my two cents.

Comment: I don't really want a library, I want a pattern I can remember, and use everywhere.

Comment: I would suggest a reading of: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/ as a reusable pattern for this.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very inefficient pattern as it creates a new constructor on every call and it doesn't leverage prototype inheritance. Also, depending only on capitalisation to indicate a constructor is not good for maintenance. At least with `new Foo()` it is clear that a new instance is being returned.

If you don't like using `new` (and I can't understand why), then wrap constructors in a calling function with a name that indicates what they do, like `newRandom` or similar.

Regarding the code, I don't know why you are using function expressions rather than declarations. There is no need to use the same name for the inner function as the outer one, in fact the inner function doesn't need a name at all:

```
function X(name) {
  return new (function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  })(name)
}

var a = X('a');
a.name; // a
```

but I am not suggesting you do that.